# how to add another version of php in winginx

Tags: php, winginx

The current Winginx build in available php are php5.6 (port 9056)  and php7.1 (port 9071)
[image]

How to add another extra version of php beside the build in one ?

I want to add php7.3 (port 9073) and php7.4 (port 9074) ?

Answer (score 0):

Winginx.exe has only support up to php72. You can download php7.2 and put files in php72 folder/ Then add port in settings.

Here i have a mod of Winginx, where detecting folders changed from 7.1-7.2 to 7.3-8.0 http://oldfag.top/downloads/?act=view&id=432
Zip archive. Because idk how create auto installer :)